# How to run two threads simultaneously and wait for the result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to run from my python code two instances of one program as different threads. And after both of them finishes I would like to do some other stuff.

Lets say I have code like that:

```
import logging
import threading
import time


def thread_function(name):
    logging.info("Thread %s: starting ", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Thread %s: finishing ", name)


def main():
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    logging.info("Main: before creating thread")
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
    logging.info("Main: before running thread")
    x.start()
    logging.info("Main: wait for the thread to finish")
    logging.info("Main: all done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code prints `Main: all done` before the two threads finish. But I would like to wait until they are finished and than print `all Done`. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: use join to wait for the threads to finish

Comment: You are talking about Processes when you are using Threads

Comment: Threads != processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [thread.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to wait for a Thread to finish.

```
import logging
import threading
import time


def thread_function(name):
    logging.info("Thread %s: starting ", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Thread %s: finishing ", name)


def main():
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    logging.info("Main: before creating thread")
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
    logging.info("Main: before running thread")
    x.start()
    logging.info("Main: wait for the thread to finish")
    x.join()
    logging.info("Main: all done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If theoretically you have more than one thread to wait for, would you have to call `thread.join()` on each of the threads individually, or would the single call suffice?

Comment: @HampusLarsson You would have to call join on each of the threads individually.

Answer (score 1):

[join(timeout=None)¶](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)

> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until
>   the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally
>   or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout
>   occurs.